# Equivalent Objective C syntax in python using pyobjc

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, pyobjc

**Edit:** To future googlers abarnert's answer works giving a NSHIObject (from HIToolbox, HI standing for human interface), I can find little more documentation on this, the only mention on apple.com (there is ZERO, ZIP, NADA documentation on a class called NSHI object as of this point https://www.google.com/#q=%22NSHIObject%22+site%3Aapple.com&filter=0 ) is 
In object c if I have the following http://lists.apple.com/archives/webkitsdk-dev/2010/Sep/msg00007.html which doesn't work for this object the NSWindow isn't created. Yay for apples api documentation.

```
NSWindow.initWithWindowRef_(nshi_object)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Expecting instance of NSWindow as self, got one of NSHIObject
```

Original Question about loading the pointer given from wxPython

---

C Code

```
// our data
int a = 42;
// create a pointer to that data
int *p = &a;
// p now contains the address (say 1776) and that address has the integer 42
// get the data back
int ret_a = *p;

// now if we already have an address
int* manual_pointer = (int*) 1776; 
int man_a = *manual_pointer;

printf("%d,%d\n", ret_a, man_a);
```

How do I do this syntax in pyobjc? I see it mentions [here](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/api/module-objc.html)

```
More complex types can be represented using longer type strings:

    a pointer to some type is _C_PTR followed by the type string of the pointed-to type.
```

So what do I do? This (if the object type is NSInt)?

```
arg = _C_PTR + "NSInt" + "1776"
```

Objective C Code (Added later)
Please note you have to somehow inject this into the python process other wise it won't work

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        char line[2048];
        // this will store are address
        long adr;
        printf("According to \n- http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=31778\n- http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=18645\n");
        printf("This will prompt you for a pointer address; please paste in the long you received from GetHandle()\n");
        printf("Please enter pointer address: ");
        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
        sscanf(line, "%ld", &adr);
        printf("Using address: %ld\n", adr);

        printf("Grabbing view...");

        // our NSView    
        NSView *view =  (__bridge NSView *)((void *)adr);

        NSRect f = view.frame;
        int w = f.size.width;
        int h = f.size.height;
        printf("Size(%d, %d)", w, h);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you showed is pure C, with no ObjC in it. The link to Objective-C type strings doesn't seem relevant here at all. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You don't mention what you are actually trying to do, which makes it hard to tell you what to do.

Comment: Anyway, the PyObjC documentation you refer to is for the documentation of Objective-C type encodings which are used to describe the type of function/method arguments. As a user of PyObjC you should have little reason to actually use those type encodings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment on bbum's answer:

> The problem is I am getting a pointer address from a C++ library (wxPython) that points to a NSView object I want to get.

For that, just use the [`objc_object`](http://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/api/module-objc.html#types) constructor:

```
view = objc.objc_object(c_void_p=ptr)
```

Of course I don't think `wxPython` gives you `ctypes.c_void_p` values for whatever function you're using to get the pointer. I don't know what it *does* give you, but the most likely possibility is an `int`, in which case you can just do this:

```
view = objc.objc_object(c_void_p=ctypes.c_void_p(ptr))
```

---

You didn't mention which version of PyObjC you're using. If it's before 2.5 (you can check `objc.version`), you either have to manually build a PyCapsule object, or do this from the other side of the bridge. I don't have an old copy to test with, or the old docs, so this is from memory, but it looked something like this:

```
view = NSView.objectWithSomethingOrOther_(ptr)
```

---

Meanwhile, from your original question:

```
arg = _C_PTR + "NSInt" + "1776"
```

I'm not sure why you're trying to build a type string in the first place, but…

The type string for a pointer to some type X is `_C_PTR` followed by the type string for X, not the name of X. Also, there is no type `NSInt`. If you meant a class type like `NSNumber`, you can just use `_C_ID` (just as you can use `id` instead of `NSNumber *` in native ObjC). If you meant an integral type `NSInteger`, that's `_C_PTR + _C_NSInteger`. If you meant an integral type that doesn't have a special name, you have to find out which type it's a typedef for and use that—for example, `_C_PTR + _C_LNG` will work for `NSInteger *` on 64-bit Macs.

Meanwhile, a type string names a type, not a value, so if that `1776` is supposed to be the pointed-to location, or the value at that location, or really anything else I can think of, that doesn't even make sense.

---

Finally, I have no idea what your C code (there's no ObjC in it anywhere) is supposed to be demonstrating, but I'm willing to bet that if you actually run it, it will segfault.

---

Meanwhile, from your comment and [your code](http://paste.pound-python.org/show/33595/), what you're trying to do doesn't actually make any sense, and can't possibly work. The fact that you're now doing it successfully is why you're crashing.

Each process has its own virtual address space. When you take a pointer from one process's address space, and use it in another process, it isn't pointing at the same objects; it's pointing at either completely different objects, or nothing at all. That's why you get that segfault: `0x000000007a6e5c90` points to an `NSView` in your wxPython program's address space, but the same address points to unmapped memory in your interactive interpreter's address space.

Also, while there are APIs to map memory regions from other processes, or to directly read and write other processes' address space, that wouldn't help you here, because if there are any pointers—including opaque internal pointers—within the object you're pointing at, you have to explicitly map *those* as well. And, in the case of ObjC objects, even *that* won't work, because ObjC depends on a (process-)global object workspace. (In theory, you could write C code that manipulates the other process's ObjC workspace directly, instead of using ObjC, but… you don't want to.)

If you want to access an `NSView` from one process in a different process, there are two ways to do it. Either you have to use high-level cross-process APIs to manipulate the window, or you have to inject code into the other process and trigger it (as, for example, F-Script Anywhere does)—or, as a minor variation of the second, attach to the other process as a debugger.

But if you're writing both programs yourself, there's a much cleaner way to do it. Write your GUI app to be externally controllable in some way. One way to do on the Mac is with an AppleScript interface. Use CocoaScripting to export an API that allows other apps to do things like move your windows around. Then use appscript or ScriptingBridge, or use a dual-language approach via NSAppleScript, to use that API, instead of trying to talk directly to your NSView objects. (You can actually export the whole NSView interface through CocoaScripting if you really want to, but that's probably not the best answer.)

Comment: Nope the c code works, of course not with 1776 but with an actual inputted address it works just fine. The reason I have that code is wxPython gives me a integer and it is supposedly a pointer to the NSView on Mac OS X

Comment: @bbum: I don't think you should have deleted your answer; the information that Python intentionally doesn't deal with pointers (so libraries like PyObjC, ctypes, win32api, etc. have to work around that if they want to) is relevant.

Comment: @Zimm3r: I addressed that use case in the main part of the answer. Is that not what you were looking for? (It would help if you told us what wxPython function you're calling, what the type of the returned value is, etc. But I'm guessing it's something like getHandle() that returns an int or long, and there is no alternative that returns anything else.)

Comment: Yes sorry I was just addressing the last point not trying to say it was something missed, my fault, and yes it is GetHandle()

Comment: Thanks for the answer python does crash but I assume that is something else and not due to your answer so I have marked it as accepted; here is the code and error if you are interested http://paste.pound-python.org/show/33595/

Comment: Now that I see your code… well, read my edited answer; it's too hard to explain in a comment.

Comment: I fixed it, the code has to be in the same process probably something to do with stopping access to other process addresses for viruses etc, it works giving me an NSHI Object (which I am now searching google to find lol)

Comment: NSHIObject - seem it to be a Human Interface object (some type of new widget set) - for anyone who later finds this from google with similar issues

Comment: For googlers similiar thing is mentioned here, still no fix http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2009-September/102742.html

Comment: @Zimm3r: `NSHIObject` is a Cocoa wrapper around a Carbon widget. Carbon is not some new thing; it's an old thing that predates Cocoa. You can't call `NSView` methods on it, but you can get its `Handle` and call Carbon functions with it. Python 2.x has deprecated [wrappers around some of Carbon](http://docs.python.org/2/library/carbon.html); to go beyond that, you need to use `ctypes` or build a C extension. If you're having trouble with that, you should ask a new question at this point.

Comment: @Zimm3r: One last hint: If you're using recent-enough versions of wxPython and wx, you can force it to use Cocoa by calling [`wxversion.select('2.9-osx_cocoa')`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wxversion-module.html). I don't know if this will get you an `NSView` where you thought you wanted one, but… it's worth a try. (And if the call fails, that means you have too old a version of wx, or a Carbon-only build.)

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't deal with pointers at all;  in fact, it actively discourages their use in all ways.   You  can use the `id()` function to retrieve the address of a Python object, but there isn't a corresponding function to go the other way (that isn't a joke).

Now, given that you have a pointer to something from C, you should be able to describe that something with the ctypes module and then treat the address as a pointer and decode at will.   But it is tricky.

Not the most concrete of examples, but the Venn diagram of people that know Python, Objective-C, and are familiar with ctypes is a rather small group (which is one big reason why you are generally better off sticking to native ObjC for iOS/Cocoa).

Comment: The problem is I am getting a pointer address from a C++ library (wxPython) that points to a NSView object I want to get, normally the api handles it (on windows and X11 it uses it as a handle and moves on but Object C and apple are different sadly.

Comment: The `id` of a PyObjC object is the Python wrapper, not the ObjC object. To get that, you use `objc.pyobjc_id`. And that _does_ have a reverse operation.

Comment: Also, I think the intersection of people that know Python, ObjC, and ctypes is probably around 75% of the PyObjC community. And I strongly disagree that you're better off sticking to native ObjC. That's like saying you're better off sticking to native C on linux or C++ on Windows. If your code has more logic than Cocoa GUI stuff, Python is a much better language than ObjC. And even for dealing with Cocoa, without PyObjC (or FScript or MacRuby) you don't have an interactive interpreter to explore with.